# Log external but not own assembly first chance exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, exception, appdomain

#### Catching Own [First Chance Exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx)

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += FirstChanceException;

private static void FirstChanceException(object sender, System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // I would like to log exceptions happening outside my assembly?
        // But this event does not receive external FirstChanceExceptions
        // (unlike Visual Studio debug output)
        myLogger.Log(e.Exception);
    }
```

#### Example

- I would like to log `A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll`
- **But not log** `A first chance exception of type 'System.DivideByZeroException' occurred in MyApp.exe`

#### Solution?

- Is there a way to get notified of those exceptions arising in dlls such as mscorlib.dll?
- Note the interest is to log in the production release, not only in debugging.

#### Why

Exceptions that occur in external dll dependencies can cause trouble, even if they are handled there.

For example, due to an exception a *null* value may be returned from an external method (instead of returning the desired output of *x*) and even though my code mostly handles such abnormal output it is useful to know what exactly went wrong and where - because while I may be able to avoid fatal exceptions then more often than not that *null* value makes part of my app non-functional. So logging the external first chance exception would provide valuable information to help rectify the issue / turn that *null* into *x*. And this may be present in only given environments / for specific users etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class to check what is the source of the exception:

```
var stackTrace = new StackTrace(e.Exception);
var sourceFrame = stackTrace.GetFrame(0);
var throwingMethod = sourceFrame.GetMethod();
var sourceAssembly = throwingMethod.DeclaringType.Assembly;
var assemblyName = sourceAssembly.GetName().Name;

bool isMyApp = assemblyName == "MyApp";
```

Comment: ... but be aware that code transformations such as inlining mean that the result might not be what you expect, especially in release builds.

Comment: Thanks for this, but unfortunately i realized AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException does not actually broadcast the WindowsBase.dll or any other external first chance exception (including those occuring in mscorlib.dll) ! Presumably it is because these are happening in a different application domain and/or process?(i dont know how it works exactly) So the root question is whether it is possible to catch those external FirstChanceExceptions at all - like the VS debugger is capable of doing?

Comment: @Cel, I hope there's a better way, but as a fallback you can consider the [Debugging API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404520.aspx)

Comment: Any guidance on where i should start / what should be used in order to do it, or is it a mountain of studying to achieve this one thing?

Comment: @Cel, I know mostly the Profiling API, if the Debugging API is similar it could be a little challenge. Can you elaborate what are you trying to achieve, why do you need to log first chance exception in 3rd party?

Comment: Quite often exceptions that occur in such dlls, even if they are handled there, cause trouble in my code e.g. due to the exception a null value is returned instead of x and even though my code mostly handles such abnormal output it is useful to know what exactly went wrong and where - to help make the involved features functional (for a given environment / user etc).

Comment: due to lack of answers to the root question, i will accept yours as the answer, because it did answer the original (misinformed) question :)